# Changer path of Resources folder in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

Is it possible in Symfony3 to change the path of resources `"app/Resources"` to something like `"default/Resources"`?

Thank you.

Comment: Basically no.  Resources is hard coded.  It's always possible I suppose to dig in deep enough to change it but there no simple config option.  You can adjust the twig search path if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding AppKernel::getRootDir().

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/kernel.html#root-directory

```
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return realpath(parent::getRootDir().'/../');
    }
}
```

Override this as your requirement.

Comment: I suspect the original poster want to change the Resources directory without breaking the entire app.  Just a guess.

Comment: Thank You Uddhab, but as Cerad said, i only want to change the resources directory.